# Why won't the select box append when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am populating a select box using javascript. When a different store name is selected, it changes back to the default. the code is as follows:

```
var selected_store = "<?php if (!empty($_POST['store'])) { echo $_POST['store']; } else { echo "-1"; } ?>";    function loadStores() {
    $('#store').html('<option value="-1">Store Name</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
            console.log(selected_store);
                console.log(stores[i]);
                if (stores[i] == selected_store) {
                            $('#store').append('<option value="'+stores[i]+'" selected>'+stores[i]+'</option>');
                } else {
                    $('#store').append('<option value="'+stores[i]+'">'+stores[i]+'</option>');
                } 
            }
        } </script>      <div id="form">
<form method='post'>
        <select>
            <option>Loan Type</option>
            <option>Payday</option>
            <option>Title</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>District Manager</option>
        </select>
        <select id="store" >
            <option value="-1">Store Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class='chart_button' name="submit" id="chart_button" value="Get Data" />
</form>
```

selected_store is always returning a -1, even when a different store is selected.

Comment: and if someone could help me get this code block formatted correctly here on stack overflow, that would be great.

Comment: FYI the best way to paste code into SO is to do Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+P then -> Ctrl+K (this automatically indents all the text properly so you don't have to).

Comment: first set names for select boxes

Comment: thank you @jason. I am new to stack overflow and still getting used to how everything works on here.

Comment: @FerozAkbar could you expand on that?

Comment: All input tags need to have a `name` in order to be available from PHP. You set `id="store"` but forgot to also add `name="store"`.